# File Download Script in PHP

Tags: php

I don't know if this is possible. 
I have a webpage with about 250 links, each on a separate line. My initial thought was to use fopen() to get the files, but it did not help much because it requires supplying the name of the file to read/download.

But the files I want to download are listed as links vertically, on one web page like so:

[image]

Those are clickable links - think of it like a directory browsing with links to files.
Is there a way to loop through those links on that page and download the files they point to?

There are roughly about 250 links in all.
Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Show us the HTML source of the webpage. Or at least the structure.

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a one-time thing, or will you be using this same script regularly to download from pages like this?

Comment: With a combination of a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`file_get_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) this should be pretty easy...

Comment: Is this for a site you have control over. EX: FTP access

Comment: that's sounds like a site cloning script

Comment: @James, It's a client site and they've provided the directory for us to download the files from there. But to manually clicking and downloading 250 links would take time. Hence the need for a simple script.

Comment: will http protocol support this?

Comment: I'd suggest the [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox extension for this, assuming it's a one-time need to download static files.

Comment: @Michael: That is a great addon, perfect for this particular job. I've come across this exact scenario OP describes several times, although there are certainly better, actual solutions (FTP?).

Comment: @Wesley What do you mean by "better, actual solutions"? It seems as though this would solve the problem.

Comment: @Michael Mior - Thanks for suggesting the DownThemAll! - it did what I needed. So there was no need for a script. If you could post your answer on its own I would mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelMior: What I mean by "better solution" is that FTP is the standard protocol for file transfer. The addon solves *this* problem, but consider a deeply nested file structure, you'd still have to click through to each directory (could be thousands).

Comment: That's why the addon allows you to traverse links ;) But I agree, FTP is designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks folks for your suggestions, I eventually wrote a small script that did what I wanted.
Will post it if anyone cares to see it.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is probably overkill for this. If the files are predictably named (and they certainly seem to be) you can do this quickly with either wget e.g.:

```
wget http://example.com/folder/file{1..1000}.png
```

Or cURL e.g.:

```
curl -O http://example.com/file[1-1000].png
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the function `file();`

This returns an array with each line of a file.

Comment: You kept changing your question.. you edited like 3 times. How am I supposed to keep up with your questions? I'm going to lose points cause of you.

Comment: I didn't change the question, I only posted the screenshot of what the file looks  like. Besides, you solution didn't help at all.

Comment: well then, as an actual answer to THIS question...
You'll need an XML or an HTML parser for php to parse the files and folders, to get the locations of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this PHP DOM parser:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It has an example right on the main page for extracting all the URL's. All you have to do is slightly modify it so that the URL's are saved to an array rather than echoed.

Once you get that array of URL's, simply use [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to grab the file and use [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to save it somewhere on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox extension for this, assuming it's a one-time need to download static files